# How do I specify multiple bootstrap actions using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I am trying to launch an EMR cluster using aws cli. There are 2 ways to give bootstrap actions in aws cli.

1. Use JSON, this is what I am currently using, but its getting very messy because all this is in a bash script and its difficult to format the json
2. Use their list commands

From their website:

```
--bootstrap-actions (list)
```

Shorthand Syntax:

```
Path=string,Args=string,string,Name=string ...
```

I am able to get 1 bootstrap action doing this way, but when I try to add a second one, it only executes whatever I list last

For example:

```
Path=string,Args=string,string,Name=string,Path=string2,Args=string2,Name=string2
```

Only string2 gets executed. Does anyone know the proper format for this?

Comment: To clarify: Are you referring to launching Amazon EMR clusters?

Comment: Yes I am, I just made an edit to the post for more clarity. Not sure why this is getting down voted though...

Comment: Downvotes are possibly because it's more systems-administration (ServerFault) than software-development (StackOverflow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears they should be **space-separated**.

From the **Add a list of bootstrap actions when creating an Amazon EMR Cluster** section of the AWS CLI [create-cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html) documentation:

```
aws emr create-cluster --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://mybucket/myscript1,Name=BootstrapAction1,Args=[arg1,arg2] Path=s3://mybucket/myscript2,Name=BootstrapAction2,Args=[arg1,arg2] --release-label emr-4.0.0  --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --auto-terminate
```

Comment: I don't see that section on the page you linked but I'll give this a try. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops! I had the wrong link. Now updated to point to the example.